# Install TFS for Business Intelligence Development Studio 2005

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2005

I have just installed BIDS via the SQL Server 2005 Developer Edition, but now I need to access and work with a TFS project.  Will I be able to install TFS suporting tools in BIDS, or will I need to do a full install of VS 2005, which I would really rather do without.  Then, I believe it is quite a process to install TFS for VS 2005, with more than  one install that must be done in the correct order etc.  Where can I find guidance on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install the Team Explorer 2005, You then need to install SP1 of VS2005, and then the forward compatibility update to be able to connect with TFS 2010. See also http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/29/How-to-connect-VS-2003-VS-2005-and-VS-2008-to-TFS-2010.aspx

If you have TFS 2008, installing Team Explorer 2005 is enough